# Количество символов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не дружу с регулярками...

Есть выражение `:"/[^a-z,A-Z,0-9,\-,\_]/"`

Нужно задать минимальное количество символов, и максимальное. (4,8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читать про [квантификаторы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9A.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.28.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B9.29):

```
"/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{4,8}/"
```

*Запятые не нужны*

Comment: Спасибо! Помог! Особенно спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: Если ответ верный, то нажмите на галочку рядом с ним, чтобы кто-то в будущем смог это понять :)

Comment: Любая строка с бэкслешем будет отвергнута этим регвыром.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff а так-же с кирилицей итд.... причем тут бэкслэш ?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, вопрос заключался только в ограничении на количество символов. Отключайте телепатию :)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, хорошо, я отключу телепатию как только вы вернёте запятые на место :-)  Вопрос был только о количестве символов.